# Proving a decimal expansion is bijective

Tags: functions, proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation, decimal-expansion

I'm trying to see if a function $f : (0, 1] × (0, 1] → (0, 1]$ is bijective, where $0.a_1a_2a_3 . . . $is the
decimal expansion of $x ∈ (0, 1]$, and $0.b_1b_2b_3 . . .$ is the decimal expansion of
$y ∈ (0, 1]$, where the decimal expansion of $f(x, y) ∈ (0, 1]$ is $0.a_1b_1a_2b_2, . . .$

I know it's injective because if two numbers, say $a$ and $c$, are different, then we have $ϵ=a−c≠0$. Since $ϵ≠0$, it must have a most significant digit. a and c must differ at that digit, or the digit before, but how can I prove it's surjective?

To add clarity: only the non-terminating decimal expansion is used in the definition of the interleaving function.

Comment: Given an element in the image you can split it into the two components required to construct it. That is if you want to hit $0.c_1 c_2 c_3 \dots $ you let $a_n=c_{2n-1}$ and $b_n=c_{2n}$ and then $f(a,b)=c$. Unless I am misunderstanding the question...which is always a possibility.

Comment: how would you get $c_1$?

Comment: Yeah. I modified it so it says $a_n=c_{2n-1}$. You are correct. I wrote the wrong index originally. But you are given an element in the image and we want to see that there is a preimage that hits it. So we let $a_1$ be $c_1$ and we let $a_2$ by $c_3$ and we continue letting $a_n$ be the numbers that appear in the odd locations of the given $c$ and likewise we construct $b$.

Comment: 0.5000... = 0.4999......

Comment: It seems like this function isn't even [well defined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-defined) unless the ambiguity in decimal expansion is resolved.

Comment: To add clarity: only the non-terminating decimal expansion is used in the definition of the interleaving function.

Comment: @BenJones:  That is correct.  In my answer I hint that no matter how you resolve the ambiguity you will have numbers that are not the image of any pair, but which numbers they are will depend on how you resolve the ambiguity.

Answer (score 2):

It is not surjective because of the numbers that have two representations.  You need to specify which representation you use on the left.  A natural one is to use the terminating form for all numbers that may terminate, so use $0.5000\ldots$ instead of $0.499999\ldots$.  No pair of numbers on the left will give a number of the form $0.a_1b_1a_29a_39a_49\ldots$ on the right.

Added:  based on the update that the non-terminating version is to be used for all the decimals that have two representations, we cannot get a number on the right of the form $0.a_15a_20a_30a_40a_40\ldots$ because that would require that $y=0.50000\ldots$

Comment: If I am understanding: the given mapping cannot construct the numbers which eventually have only $9$s in their even or odd locations.

And the first sentence says that the mapping isn't really "well-defined" because if we $f(0.5,0.5) = f(0.499\dots, 0.499\dots)$ we get $f(0.5,0,5)=0.55$ and $f(0.499\dots, 0.499\dots)=0.44999\dots$

Comment: To add clarity: only the non-terminating decimal expansion is used in the definition of the interleaving function.

Comment: This answer implies that if we pick the non-terminating expansion,  0.xxx0x0x0... cannot be mapped to.

Comment: but he does use the terminating form in his answer

Comment: Yes. I am curious about this too...
We only interpret decimals as their infinite decimal representations. What elements $a,b$ map to $0.55$? 
Well... we can clearly find elements which will map to $0.54999\dots$ so $a=0.6=0.599\dots$ and $b=.5=0.4999\dots$ does the trick. Also we can consider $f(\frac{1}{9},0.5)=0.1419191919\dots$ so we can construct numbers of this form $0.xxx0x0x0$ I think.

Comment: @Mason:  No, that is the point.  For $a=0.5$ and $a=0.6$  you need to choose a specific representation.  If you choose the terminating  version, as I suggested, the only way to map to $0.55$ is to have $a=0.5, b=0.5$.  You can also choose the $9999$ version, but that just moves the problem.  You can even choose a mix of $000$ and $999$ versions for different terminating decimals, but you will always be able to find ones that are not covered in the image. If you make a uniform choice, as I suggested choosing the $000$ version$ it is easy to exhibit some numbers that are not covered.

Comment: So is it easy to give an example of something not in the image of $f$ if we elect to always choose the $999\dots$ representation?

Comment: @Mason: yes, just pick something that has $0$s in all the even places, just like my example with $9$s in all the even places if you pick the $000\ldots$ version.